# How to do auto-login without leaving your account open to everyone?

Tags: login, auto-login

I always use only one account on my computer.

I do have a lot of programs in startup and I need them all. The problem is that they take some time to load (for example eclipse).

is there any way to do auto-login on the account and lock screen so no-one else can use my account?

Answer (score 3):

Use `gnome-screensaver-command -l` right after the list of programs you load.

It will lock your screen when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a utility like **preload** to load the applications into memory for you prior to login:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

Then Eclipse, Firefox and friends should start up in a jiffy.  I haven't tried it myself, though, and you should probably read up on how it works and how to configure it.